# Мандарин - и мандарин

Tags: омонимы

Мне давно интересно: то, что мандарин - это и фрукт, и китайский чиновник, совпадение или одно названо в честь другого?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Мандарин (порт. mandarim — министр, чиновник, от санскр. — мантрин — советник) — данное португальцами название чиновников в имперском Китае, позднее также в Корее и Вьетнаме. Название происходит через португальское посредство (слово mandarim, обозначающее министра) из санскрита (mandari — командир).

Слово «мандарин» в значении фрукт заимствовано из испанского языка (вероятно, через французское посредство). Испанское название mandarino образовано от se mondar ‘легко очищаться’ и содержит, таким образом, указание на свойство кожуры плода легко отделяться от мякоти.

В русском языке слово известно с середины 19 века, например, у Гончарова во "Фрегате "Паллада": "Мандарины - род мелких, но очень сладких и пахучих апельсинов". В 19 веке мандарины у нас называли "корольками", вероятно сравнивая их с чиновниками-мандаринами.